# How to modify job parameter on spring batch?

Tags: kotlin, spring-batch

I've managed to get a job parameter context on a `Tasklet` but I didn't figure out how to change this value so the next `Tasklet` can access a modified value

```
val params = JobParametersBuilder()
    .addString("transaction", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
    .addDouble("amount", 0.0)

jobLauncher.run(
    paymentPipelineJob,
    params.toJobParameters()
)
```

First task:

```
override fun beforeStep(stepExecution: StepExecution) {
    logger.info("[$javaClass] - task initialized.")

    this.amount = stepExecution.jobParameters.getDouble("amount")

    // Prints 0.0
    logger.info("before step: ${this.amount}")
}

override fun afterStep(stepExecution: StepExecution): ExitStatus? {
    // Change the execution content to pass it to the next step
    stepExecution.jobExecution.executionContext.put("amount", this.amount!! + 3)

    // Still prints 0.0
    logger.info("after step: ${stepExecution.jobParameters.getDouble("amount")}")
    logger.info("[$javaClass] - task ended.")
    return ExitStatus.COMPLETED
}
```

How can I modify a job parameter so all the steps can access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the execution context is a mutable object, job parameters [are](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParameters.html) [immutable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParameters.html#getParameters--). Therefore, it is not possible to modify them once the execution is launched.

That said, according to the code you shared, you are putting an attribute `amount` in the job execution context and expecting to see the modified value from the job parameters instance. This is a wrong expectation. The execution context and the job parameters are two distinct objects and are not "inter-connected".

**Edit: Add suggestion about how to address the use case**

You can use the execution context to share data between steps. You are already doing this in your example:

```
stepExecution.jobExecution.executionContext.put("amount", this.amount!! + 3)
```

Once that is done in a listener **after** step 1, you can get the value from the EC in a listener **before** step 2:

```
double amount = stepExecution.jobExecution.executionContext.get("amount");
```

Please check [Passing Data to Future Steps](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps) from the reference documentation.

Comment: Is there a way to address this situation?

Comment: I don't think so because job parameters are immutable by design. Just curious, may I ask why would you need to modify job parameters afterwards? What is the use case for that?

Comment: I'm building a `pipeline` that needs to apply a certain rule on each step and pass the information forward, what I need is to pass to the next step the data modified so the next step can apply his own rules on top of the previous modification.

Comment: You can use the execution context for that (not job parameters). The EC is mutable and is a typically used for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you add to your answer this suggestion? and some examples?

Comment: I added more details. HTH.